# The Android Studio, Android projects how to import the jar package, cover Android jar package is already available in the package?

Tags: android, jar, addition

I got class.jar,it cover android.jar package is already available in the package and add some new method. How can I import the jar package to my android project In Android Studio?

the project download url:
http://pan.baidu.com/s/1dDper2x

the class.jar download url:
 http://pan.baidu.com/s/1hqsvW5Q

Comment: As per new project structure they are already providing folder for `jar`. You need to copy `jar` files into `lib` folder. `Gradle` files already have dependencies for that `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])`

Answer (score 2):

```
Project Structure > Modules > Dependencies > Add Files
```

Browse to the location of `jar` file and select it

or

```
dependencies {
    compile files('src/main/libs/xxx.jar')
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I tested your method and got an error.Can you test it by yourself?